# Magento - Loading root collection loads all products

Tags: magento

Regarding using multiple stores, with different root categories:

I have 2 stores set up, with different roots. One has 14 products, the other 6.

If I use the following on my homepage (simply to show how many products are in the root category for that store - in this case with an ID of 8) I get 20 products - so all products in the store, from all roots:

```
$_testproductCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(8)  
->getProductCollection()  
->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load();
echo "NO. OF PRODUCTS IS ".$_testproductCollection->count();
```

However, if I change the ID to a sub-category, I get the correct amount of products. There are only 6 products in this root:

[image: roots]

But the count shows 20 (as there's 20 in the whole store - or both roots).

Anyone know what's up? Is it a bug?

I also noticed that if you go to Manage Products and use the store view filter, it doesn't do anything, still showing 20 products in the store view whose root has only 6 products:

[image: filter]

Comment: I have the same problem in Magento.
Has you found a solution for this problem?

Comment: I would just use the subcategory. As far as I can tell, root categories are just used for multi-store set ups, not used for any type of category/product filtering. For example, even if I set as inactive the root category for a store, the subcategories still show for that store. So, just use the subcategory and don't think about it unless you want to plumb the innards of spaghetti magento code.

Comment: @dani No, still haven't found a solution, although i have submitted a bug report to Magento. If I do come up with a workaround, I'll be sure to post it up. @David, using sub-categories isn't really fixing the problem, as you can't use a sub-category as the root for separate stores.

Comment: Another thing I was thinking is, how come the categories are correctly filtered by current store root? If I add different categories to each root, they show correctly in the menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think this works, haven't tested too much but seems to have done the trick. You need to first get your stores root category id, then join some fields so you have access to the products "category_id", then filter using that:

```
$_rootcatID = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();

$_testproductCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
->joinField('category_id','catalog/category_product','category_id','product_id=entity_id',null,'left')
->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $_rootcatID))
->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$_testproductCollection->load();

foreach($_testproductCollection as $_testproduct){ 
    echo $this->htmlEscape($_testproduct->getName())."<br/>"; 
};
```